# Is there a better way to write information from a for loop to .txt file?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests

I'm building a URL Checker that finds broken URLS that I give it then sends an email to me with the results. This is my end result. I had to create another file to write to inside of my for loop then send that file. It works but is there a cleaner way to do this and not have two .txt files and not overwrite what is in the original testurls.txt?

```
import requests
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage


with open ("testurls.txt", "r") as txt_file:
    for urls in txt_file:
        request = requests.get(urls)
        try:
            request.raise_for_status()
        except Exception as error:
            error = 'There was a problem: %s' % (error)

            with open("listurls.txt", "r+") as f:       
                f.truncate(0)                           #Deletes the files pre existing data
                f.writelines(error+ "\n")               #Writes the new data
            f.close()
        else:
            pass
with open("listurls.txt", "r") as file_to_send:
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(file_to_send.read())

msg['Subject'] = "Here are the list of URLs that don't work"
msg['From'] = 'andrewtalbotprogramming@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'andrewtalbotprogramming@gmail.com'

s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=465)
print("Enter Your Password To Continue")
password = input('')
s.login('andrewtalbotprogramming@gmail.com',password)

s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
with open("listurls.txt", "r+") as f:       
    f.truncate(0)                           #Deletes the files pre existing data
    f.writelines(error+ "\n")               #Writes the new data
f.close()
```

can be simply done as this:

```
with open("listurls.txt", "w") as f:       
    f.writelines(error+ "\n")               # Write the new data
```

notice, you don't need `f.close()` if you're using `with open(...)`.

Having said that, I don't understand why you need to overwrite this file for EACH URL, the more reasonable approach would be to log all broken URLs, not just the last one (you overwrite the file, remember?), and have all broken links included in your e-mail.

Another improvement would be to provide just the root URL for the web site, and recursively extract the pages and collect all links automatically. Not sure if this is what you need, though.

Comment: I ended up using 
with open("listurls.txt", "w") as f:       
    f.truncate(0)
Before my code and then I  used append instead of the "w"

with open("listurls.txt", "a") as f: